# Strange behaviour of svg-images in IE

Tags: internet-explorer, svg

Can anyone help me figure out why all but one SVG are displayed on this website using IE (10/11):

http://azubi.lotter.de/

Headlines and buttons have a blue background image (SVGs). All but one (the one that says "Jetzt bewerben" at the bottom of the section "Berufe") are showing just fine in IE. When playing around in the inspector I get the last SVG to appear when I...

...set position: relative **AND**
...set display: block

However the SVGs that are being correctly displayed are also **set to absolute and/or block**.

This doesn't make any sense to me! Although I could probably sort this out by hacking my CSS until I get the SVG to appear somehow, but I'd like to understand what happens here.

Comment: That button is showing up correctly for me in IE11.

Comment: Seriously? Damn, now that adds even more confusion ;-)
How about IE10?

Comment: I don't have IE10 installed, but in IE10 Document Mode it shows up.

Comment: IE is going to kill me one day... xD